# How can I houserule Arkham Horror to include having one player character attacking another player character?

Tags: house-rules, arkham-horror

Sometimes I just feel like throwing a bit of anarchy into whatever game I am playing. What are the rules for one player character attacking another player character? How does the battle play out?

Comment: This seems pretty difficult to answer without some idea of what you have in mind. Is the goal of the game still for everyone to win? Do you want it to still be winnable reasonably frequently? Do you specifically want player vs player anarchy, not just more unplanned stuff going wrong of the sort that there's already tons of in Arkham Horror?

Comment: I've read just about everything published from ol' HP. It's not out of the realm. It also seems kind of fun. The people I play with are fond of closing gates while player characters are on the plains. I'm not seeing any real difference as losing sanity or stamina just lands you in either the hospital or sanitarium. Closing the portal on someone puts them in time out. The game plays a lot like a Gothic version of Clue. :)

Answer (score 2):

There are no rules for players attacking other players, not to say you can't devise your own to make the game even harder to win cooperatively than it already is.  I would imagine you might want to draw those lines at the outset, have it discovered in secret, or have it revealed to all by chance mid-game.  Arkham Horror is pretty complex in itself so you'd want to think about several cases like how your character would assist the dark side, but it would be interesting narratively.

Have fun with it, but the answer to your question remains that there are no official rules for attacking one another. (It would be fun to play the antagonist and move a few monsters or choose between 2 mythos cards to inflict upon them, though, to spice up the flow of the narrative.)

Answer (score 1):

In fact there is a possibility to play against other players.

In Dunwich Horror expansion there is a mission card [Joining the winning team](http://www.arkhamhorrorwiki.com/Joining_the_Winning_Team).
You have to sacrifice allies in some locations. If you manage to do this - you win the game, and others loose.

Answer (score -3):

If you like to introduce some variant in your game, you can try the [Arkham Horor League](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/79636/arkham-horror-league-season-1-2008-all-one).

Comment: Welcome to Board Games Stack Exchange! I wasn't the one who downvoted your answer, but I'm guessing it was downvoted because it doesn't really answer the original question and is more commentary. The Arkham Horror League is indeed an interesting variant, but it's not about PVP combat like the person was looking for. Still, hopefully you can answer some other questions on this site, or ask your own!